# how to refer a directive to MySql.Data.MySqlClient to connect mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

When I try run my program in a webserver with MySql database, it gives the following compilation error,

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 2:  using System.Data;
> Line 3:  
> Line 4:  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
> Line 5:  
> Line 6:  namespace MySQL_test
> ```

What is wrong with the code given below,

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MySQL_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connstring = 
                        @"server=localhost:3306;userid=abc123;
                                password=qMv87p3N2s;database=testDB";

            MySqlConnection conn = null;

            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
                conn.Open();

                string query = "SELECT * FROM table_name;";
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "table_name");
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["table_name"];

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        Response.Write(row[col] + "\t");
                    }

                    Response.Write("\n");                  
                }           
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you download, install and reference the mysql .net connector?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your project and upload all bin DLLs, if you already did this then re reference the 
mysql.dll from your project /bin/debug/directory